# How to save a button's isSelected() property in onSaveInstanceState and later restore it using onRestoreInstanceState?

Tags: java, android

I want to save a button's isSelected() property in onSaveInstanceState and later restore it using onRestoreInstanceState when rotating the device. Its a dice game where, i have three kind of dice, on throw the active dices (white), on selecting any dice (red), after selecting and scoring deactivated dices are black.

Once i have thrown, selected, and scored, and rotate the phone, the active dices are restored , the deactivated dices can also be restored, but i want to restore the dice that i may have clicked (but not scored, as scoring will make them deactivated black dice) before rotating the phone.

```
//Change the dice icon on selection
private void setSelectDice(ImageButton imgBtn, int face, boolean stat) {

    imgBtn.setSelected(stat);
    if (stat) {
        imgBtn.setImageResource(imgSelectedDice[face-1]);
    }  
}

//save instance
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putIntArray("diceValues", diceFaces);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("totalScore", diceAction.getTotalScore());

        //dice action is a handler class that has certain dice operation
        //this part is working fine where i want to restore the active dices that i have thrown
        List<Integer> activeDiceList = diceAction.getCurrentDice();
        int[] activeDice = new int[activeDiceList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < activeDiceList.size(); i++) {
            activeDice[i] = activeDiceList.get(i);
        }
        savedInstanceState.putIntArray("activeDice", activeDice);

        //Here i got stuck, I am trying to use the same techniques above to create a list  of selected dice
        ArrayList<Integer> selDiceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] selDice = new int[selDiceList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < imgBtnDice.length; i++) {
            if (imgBtnDice[i].isSelected()) {
                selDiceList.add(i);
                selDice[i] = selDiceList.get(i);
            }
        }
        savedInstanceState.putIntArray("selectedDice", selDice);

    }


@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        diceFaces = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("diceValues");

        //Array of active dice, working fine
        int[] activeDice = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("activeDice");
        //Array of selected dice, ???
        int[] selDice = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("selectedDice");

        boolean isThrowableStat = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("throwStat");
        boolean isSavableStat = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("saveStat");
        diceAction = new DiceHandler(diceFaces, activeDice, isThrowableStat, isSavableStat);

        diceAction.setTotalScore(savedInstanceState.getInt("totalScore"));
        // Creating a list of current dice and traversing it to set up active dice image and deactivated dice image, working fine

        List<Integer> activeDiceList = diceAction.getCurrentDice();
        for (int i = 0; i < diceFaces.length; i++) {
            imgBtnDice[i].setImageResource(imgActiveDice[diceFaces[i] - 1]);    
            setDeactiveDice(imgBtnDice[i], diceFaces[i], activeDiceList.contains(i));

        }

        //trying to do the same technique as above but not working
        List<Integer> selectedDiceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < diceFaces.length; i++) {
            setSelectDice(imgBtnDice[i], diceFaces[i], selectedDiceList.contains(i));
        }

        tvRound.setText(diceAction.getRoundNr().toString());
        tvFinalScore.setText(diceAction.getTotalScore().toString());
        tvTurnScore.setText(diceAction.getRoundScore().toString());

    }
```

Help is highly appreciated. Is there any other way (than mentioned above) i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here some lake of knowledge problem, `onRestoreInstanceState` method called after `onCreate` method so you have to check all save state in `onCreate`. see below code

```
onCreate(Bundle b){
.....
.....
if(b!=null){
.....
.....     
//paste here your onRestoreInstanceState code thats it and Remove onRestoreInstanceState method no need it.
}
}
```

Thats it...

Comment: I already have this piece of code in OnCreate()                           // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            runGreed();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Have tried you tried adding **android:configChanges** node to your Activity's manifest xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```